# Why is this question indicating a Fraunhofer Region rather than Fresnel Region?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

I was thinking that because the source plane is infinitely large would be analogous to having the source plane being infinitely close, which would imply a Fresnel region rather than Fraunhofer.

[image]

Equation 1.36 is the Fraunhofer region integration formula.
[image]

Comment: From which textbook is this material ?

Comment: @my2cts http://optics.sgu.ru/~ulianov/Students/Books/Applied_Optics/Keigo%20Iizuka%20Elements%20of%20Photonics.%20Vol%201.pdf

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users.

Answer (score 0):

This is too big for a comment so I'm putting it in an answer.

From

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field

*the near field is that part of the radiated field that is below distances shorter than the Fraunhofer distance[1] $d_f = 2D^2∕λ$ from the source of the diffracting edge or antenna of longitude or diameter D.*

MY ANSWER:
If the aperture size $D$ is taken to be infinite (if the aperture is assumed to be the film size) then the diffraction pattern would be from the Fresnel zone--as you say.

Did he also give an aperture size that you did not put in the question?

Comment: no, there was no other information that I omitted other than some diagrams

Comment: Then I think this would be in the Fresnel region where the Fourier transform does not apply--as you said.  Do the diagrams contain an aperture size or show an aperture?

Comment: http://optics.sgu.ru/~ulianov/Students/Books/Applied_Optics/Keigo%20Iizuka%20Elements%20of%20Photonics.%20Vol%201.pdf

Comment: It is on page 555 and 103 if you want to take a look at it

Comment: I looked-thanks.  Saw nothing to change my comment.

Answer (score 0):

For Fraunhofer diffraction the angles of the waves at the observation point should be small and the distance should be large with respect to the wavelength. Since the source plane is stated to be "infinitely large" the first condition cannot be met and the solution is not the Fourier transform. Less strictly speaking "infinitely large" probably is intended to mean "ignore edge effects" in which case the answer *is* the FT.